# How to create a custom UILabel in Swift with a specific color

Tags: swift, uilabel

I am trying to create a custom UILabel where the text color would be red.
Here's what I tried and none of this works:

```
class CustomLabel: UILabel {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        UILabel.appearance().textColor = UIColor.blue
        textColor = UIColor.blue
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you set `CustomLabel` to label inside IB ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing another case, a `Label` can be created with and without nib. Try this:

```swift
class MyCustomLabel: UILabel {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        // This will call `awakeFromNib` in your code
        setup()
    }
    
    private func setup() {
        self.textColor = .red
    }
}
```